# How to hide window screen and show screen after a time interval in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a problem that in my app i don't want to show any type of screen and when application install on device but after 2 minutes i want to show a screen. I am  using following code for this

```
   -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{


    // after 30 seconds it will show a view
    [self performSelector:@selector(show_view) withObject:nil afterDelay:30];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

But when i run app on device then it show a black screen for a moment and then show a white screen. And after 30 second of white screen it add new view on current window.

But i want that when it  install on device then it will start a thread in background immediately  and direct show last view. Don't show any other view or screen.

How to apply that in application?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application which work in background only iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678710/application-which-work-in-background-only-iphone)

Comment: **Please don't post same questions multiple times** with different formation of sentences but same meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you looking when the application is loading that time we can't handle that moment for that you need to use the one image put that place called the splash screen.

You need to just one image which size is into iPhone is 320*460 image and give the name of the images is "Default.png". and put into resource folder.

That's better solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this. When you start an application, it is shown immediately to the user. The white screen that you see is the window, which is the first view. Even if you leave "[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]" out you will still see a black screen.

You might now think about closing down your app programmatically right after the start and automatically relaunch it 30 seconds later, but both is also not possible.